# List down column headers and get the maximum length of string per column

Tags: excel, powershell, vbscript, vba

I'm looking for a translation of my Excel formula in a form of a script in Powershell, vbscript or Excel VBA. I'm trying to get the list of column headers and the max length of string under it.

Normally, what I do is manually open the .txt file in Excel, from there I can get the header names.. next, I create an array formula **=MAX(LEN(A1:A100,000))** for example. This will get the max length of string in the column. I'll do the same formula to other columns.

Right now I can't do this since files have increased to 1GB in size and i can't open them anymore, my desktop crashes. It is also maybe because theyre more than 1 million rows which Excel cant handle. My friend suggested Powershell but I have limited knowledge there.. don't know if it can be done in vbscript or Excel VBA.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Below code works for .csv files but does not with .txt delimited files -

```
$fileName = "C:\Desktop\EFile.csv"
<#
Sample format of c:\temp\data.csv
"id","name","grade","address"
"1","John","Grade-9","test1"
"2","Ben","Grade-9","test12222"
"3","Cathy","Grade-9","test134343"
#>
$colCount = (Import-Csv  $fileName | Get-Member | Where-Object {$_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty'} | Measure-Object).Count
$csv = Import-Csv $fileName 
$csvHeaders = ($csv | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty).name

$dict = @{}
foreach($header in $csvHeaders) {
    $dict.Add($header,0)
    }

foreach($row in $csv)
{
    foreach($header in $csvHeaders) 
    {
        if($dict[$header] -le ($row.$header).Length) 
        {
            $dict[$header] =($row.$header).Length
        }
    }
}
$dict.Keys | % { "key = $_ , Column Length = " + $dict.Item($_) }
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post, I do it previously in Excel.. where I open the .txt file, get the header names and insert the formula. However I can't do this anymore since Excel crashes, probably due to more than 1 million rows of records. My desktop eventually crashes.

Comment: Please pare down your code to the smallest possible example that illustrates your problem and post the code here. We're happy to help when we have the exact code you're working with instead of having to ask dozens of questions.

Comment: Hi, updated the post. That is the script he uses on his .csv files but iit runs differently with .txt delimited files. He dont know what to do in .txt delimited version.

Comment: "csv" stands for Comma Separated Values, there's no ".txt delimited" standard - you'll need to `Import-Csv $filename -Delimiter "\`t"` but using whatever the delimiter is - tab, pipe, space, etc.

Comment: Hi TessellatingHeckler , yes it's pipe delimited.

Comment: Then `Import-Csv $fileName -Delimiter "|"` should make it act like a CSV

Answer (score 1):

This is how I get my data.

```
$data = @"
"id","name","grade","address"
"1","John","Grade-9","test1"
"2","Ben","Grade-9","test12222"
"3","Cathy","Grade-9","test134343"
"@
$csv = ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ',' $data
```

But you should get your data like this

```
$fileName = "C:\Desktop\EFile.csv"
$csv = Import-Csv -Path $fileName
```

And then

```
# Extract the header names
$headers = $csv | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

# Capture output in $result variable
$result = foreach($header in $headers) {

    #                 Select all items in $header column,     find the longest,         and select the item for output
    $maximum = $csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $header | Measure-Object -Maximum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Maximum

    # Generate new object holding the information. 
    # This will end up in $results
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Header = $header
        Max = $maximum.Length
        String = $maximum
    }
}


# Simple output
$result | Format-Table
```

This is what I get:

```
Header  Max String    
------  --- ------    
address  10 test134343
grade     7 Grade-9   
id        1 3         
name      4 John
```

Alternatively, if you have memory issues dealing with large files, you may have to get a bit more dirty with the .NET framework. This snippet processes one csv line at a time, instead of reading the entire file into memory.

```
$fileName = "$env:TEMP\test.csv"
$delimiter = ','

# Open a StreamReader
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($fileName)

# Read the headers and turn it into an array, and trim away any quotes
$headers = $reader.ReadLine() -split $delimiter | % { $_.Trim('"''') }

# Prepare a hashtable for the results
$result = @{}

# So long as there's more data, keep running
while(-not $reader.EndOfStream) {

    # Read a single line and process it as csv
    $csv = $reader.ReadLine() | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $headers -Delimiter $delimiter

    # Determine if the item in the result hashtable is smaller than the current, using the header as a key
    foreach($header in $headers) {
        $item = $csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $header

        if($result[$header].Maximum -lt $item.Length) {
            $result[$header] = [pscustomobject]@{
                Header = $header
                Maximum = $item.Length
                String = $item
            }
        }
    }
}

# Clean up our spent resource
$reader.Close()

# Simple output
$result.Values | Format-Table
```

Comment: `Measure-Object -Maximum` on a string column gets the max string by alphanumeric comparison, not the maximum length one. It works in your example, but that's only because the two are the same. If you added another string, say for example "z", that would show up as the max value.

Comment: @mtnielsen, great script but @UnionP is correct. As written, all integers are reported with a length of 1. First set your "Max" equal to a string and it should be accurate:
    `Max = (($maximum).ToString()).Length`